# What's wrong with my model?

Tags: entity-framework

I've created model named Level and now I'm trying to use Seed method to fill a database. Here's a model:

```
public class Level
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid LevelId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Course")]
    public Guid CourseId { get; set; }

    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Stage> Stages { get; set; }
}
```

And here's a piece of Seed method

```
context.Courses.AddOrUpdate(
            c => c.Name,
            new Course() { Name = "C# for beginners", LanguageId = context.Languages.FirstOrDefault(k => k.Name == "C#").LanguageId, UserId = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Login == "user1").UserId },
            new Course() { Name = "Advanced C++", LanguageId = context.Languages.FirstOrDefault(k => k.Name == "C++").LanguageId, UserId = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Login == "user2").UserId }
           );

        context.Levels.AddOrUpdate(
            l => l.Name,
            new Level() { Name = "Level 1", CourseId = context.Courses.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Name == "C# for beginners").CourseId },
            new Level() { Name = "Level 2", CourseId = context.Courses.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Name == "C# for beginners").CourseId },
            new Level() { Name = "Level 1", CourseId = context.Courses.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Name == "Advanced C++").CourseId }
            );
```

I have a lot of problems with Levels. One time I had only 2 objects in database instead of 3, now I have

> Sequence contains more than one element

error and I don't know why, few minutes ago I've updated database and everything was ok. What's wrong with it?

Thank you

Comment: You have two "Level 1" at Levels.AddOrUpdate.

Comment: `AddOrUpdate` doesn't save changes, so when the database is empty, `context.Courses.FirstOrDefault(d => ...` doesn't yield anything.